# Laravel Error Import Error Query Duplicate Data

Tags: laravel

I Want to Make Validation Duplicate Data in Import, but when I want to import, I get duplicate data response but, in DB has no data at all

```
public function importFile(Request $request, $urlTable) {
    $table = config('import.' . $urlTable);
    $data = json_decode($request->input('data_import'));
    $selectedField = config('import.'.$table);       
    $totalField = count($selectedField);

    // build insert query
    $query1 = "INSERT INTO $table (";
    $query1 .= 'id_well_track' . ', ';
    foreach ($selectedField as $i => $column) {
        if (empty($column)) {
            continue;
        }
        $query1 .= $column;
        $query1 .= ($totalField == ($i+1))? ')' : ', ';
    }

    DB::beginTransaction();
    try {
        foreach ($data as $values) {
            if (DB::table('well_drilling_raw')->where('id_well_track', $request->id_well_track_param)->where('timestamp', $values[0])->exists()) {
                $response = [
                    'title' => 'Error Duplicate Data !',
                    'text' => 'Duplicate In ' . $values[0]
                ];
                return response()->json($response, 400);
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DB::beginTransaction();` and i guess you have somewhere `rollback()` so between this two you have `return response()->json($response, 400);` that leads to rollback of you db transaction(inserting data) check [here](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/database).
That is why you don't have data in db.So you have few choices:

1. Skip when duplicate is detected and just warn or log. Continue to insert
2. `Db:commit()` before return if you want previous data to save.
3. Or use laravel eloquent `Model::updateOrCreate([...])` check [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#other-creation-methods)